# Invalid argument to connect()

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to write code to setup a client socket that can send/receive messages from a server. Here's what I have:

```
// Create the socket
int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // TODO: error checking

// Setup the client and server addresses
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));
cli_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
cli_addr.sin_port = htons(7654);
cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(11111);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");

// Bind the socket to the client address (so we can receive messsages)
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(errno);
}
// Connect the socket to the server address (so we can send messages)
if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) {
    perror("connect failed");
    exit(errno);
}
```

When I run this, I'm getting the error `connect failed: Invalid argument`. I don't see what I'm doing incorrectly here, though.

Comment: Read your own comment on the socket call.

Comment: @stark I don't think that's the issue because it's not failing for `bind`, which is called before `connect`.

Comment: I just added error checking around `socket` and it still happens.

Comment: If you bind to 127.0.0.1 you cannot connect to anything but the localhost. You don't need to bind the client socket at all. So don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
...
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

You'll bind the socket to localhost (127.0.0.1) but then you connect to an address which likely is not localhost. There is no way such a TCP with a fully internal IP address (i.e. not accessible from outside the machine) to an IP address of a different system can be created, hence *"Invalid argument"*.

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve with the `bind` in the first place so it might be the best to just remove it. In this case it will automatically pick a local IP and port which can be used in a connection to the given destination IP.

Comment: Removing `bind` gets rid of the error with `connect`, but I think I need it somewhere since later on I try to receive messages from the server. Currently I'm getting a segfault at `recv`.

Comment: @JamesKo: You don't need to explicitly `bind` before `connect` in order  to receive data. It is actually the most common case to have no explicit `bind` on the client side. Your segfault in `recv` is caused by a different problem - I recommend to ask a new question about this which includes the code where the problem happens.